# Count & loop created class objects

Tags: java

Following the Oracle Acadamy Java Fundamentals and I walked into a wall(I dont understand how its explained in the acadamy)

> 8. Modify the method nicestFish to take be a variable argument method that takes in a variable number of fish and returns the nicest fish out of the fish it is given.  Hint: Inside of the method, create a new fish called temp.  Set temp equal to the first fish passed into the method.  Use a for loop to go through all the fish passed into the method and if you discover a fish that is more friendly than temp, set temp equal to that fish.  After the for loop is complete, temp should be the friendliest fish.  Return temp.

Main

```
public class index {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Fish Amber = new Fish("AngelFish", 5);
    Fish James = new Fish("Guppy", 3);
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Class

```
public class Fish {
String typeOfFish;
int friendliness;
public Fish(){
    typeOfFish = "unknown";
    friendliness = 3;
}
public Fish(String t, int f){
    this.typeOfFish = t;
    this.friendliness = f;
}
public int getFriendliness(){
    return friendliness;
}
public static Fish nicestFish(Fish Amber, Fish James){
    Fish temp = new Fish();
    if(Amber.getFriendliness()>James.getFriendliness()){
        return Amber;
    }
    else{
        return James;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: How do I make the for loop run for the made objects?

Comment: If i understood correctly, the `nicestFish` function should have array or list of fishes as parameter, and you should use for loop to iterate through the array/list and compare them.